# Python : How to add vertical scroll in RecycleView

Tags: python, kivy

I am using `Python-2.7` and `kivy`.
I run `test.py` then show a menu `Test`.When i click on it then show `list` of data. 
Can someone tell me how to add vertical `scrollbar` on list.

## test.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import BooleanProperty, ListProperty, ObjectProperty, NumericProperty, DictProperty

from kivy.uix.recycleview.views import RecycleDataViewBehavior
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.recyclegridlayout import RecycleGridLayout
from kivy.uix.behaviors import FocusBehavior
from kivy.uix.recycleview.layout import LayoutSelectionBehavior
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.clock import Clock

Window.size = (600, 325)

class SelectableRecycleGridLayout(FocusBehavior, LayoutSelectionBehavior,
                                  RecycleGridLayout):
    ''' Adds selection and focus behaviour to the view. '''

    selected_row = NumericProperty(0)

    def get_nodes(self):
        nodes = self.get_selectable_nodes()
        if self.nodes_order_reversed:
            nodes = nodes[::-1]
        if not nodes:
            return None, None

        selected = self.selected_nodes
        if not selected:    # nothing selected, select the first
            self.select_node(nodes[0])
            self.selected_row = 0
            return None, None

        if len(nodes) == 1:     # the only selectable node is selected already
            return None, None

        last = nodes.index(selected[-1])
        self.clear_selection()
        return last, nodes

    def select_next(self):
        ''' Select next row '''
        last, nodes = self.get_nodes()
        if not nodes:
            return

        if last == len(nodes) - 1:
            self.select_node(nodes[0])
            self.selected_row = nodes[0]
        else:
            self.select_node(nodes[last + 1])
            self.selected_row = nodes[last + 1]

    def select_previous(self):
        ''' Select previous row '''
        last, nodes = self.get_nodes()
        if not nodes:
            return

        if not last:
            self.select_node(nodes[-1])
            self.selected_row = nodes[-1]
        else:
            self.select_node(nodes[last - 1])
            self.selected_row = nodes[last - 1]

    def select_current(self):
        ''' Select current row '''
        last, nodes = self.get_nodes()
        if not nodes:
            return

        self.select_node(nodes[self.selected_row])


class SelectableButton(RecycleDataViewBehavior, Button):
    ''' Add selection support to the Button '''
    index = None
    selected = BooleanProperty(False)
    selectable = BooleanProperty(True)

    def refresh_view_attrs(self, rv, index, data):
        ''' Catch and handle the view changes '''

        self.index = index
        return super(SelectableButton, self).refresh_view_attrs(rv, index, data)

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        ''' Add selection on touch down '''
        if super(SelectableButton, self).on_touch_down(touch):
            return True
        if self.collide_point(*touch.pos) and self.selectable:
            print("on_touch_down: self=", self)
            return self.parent.select_with_touch(self.index, touch)

    def apply_selection(self, rv, index, is_selected):
        ''' Respond to the selection of items in the view. '''
        self.selected = is_selected


class RV(BoxLayout):
    data_items = ListProperty([])
    row_data = DictProperty({})
    col1_data = ListProperty([])
    col2_data = ListProperty([])
    col1_row_controller = ObjectProperty(None)
    col2_row_controller = ObjectProperty(None)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(RV, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.get_states()
        Clock.schedule_once(self.set_default_first_row, .0005)
        self._request_keyboard()

    def _request_keyboard(self):
        self._keyboard = Window.request_keyboard(
            self._keyboard_closed, self, 'text'
        )
        if self._keyboard.widget:
            # If it exists, this widget is a VKeyboard object which you can use
            # to change the keyboard layout.
            pass
        self._keyboard.bind(on_key_down=self._on_keyboard_down)

    def _keyboard_closed(self):
        self._keyboard.unbind(on_key_down=self._on_keyboard_down)
        self._keyboard = None

    def _on_keyboard_down(self, keyboard, keycode, text, modifiers):
        if keycode[1] == 'down':    # keycode[274, 'down'] pressed
            # Respond to keyboard down arrow pressed
            self.display_keystrokes(keyboard, keycode, text, modifiers)
            self.col1_row_controller.select_next()
            self.col2_row_controller.select_next()

        elif keycode[1] == 'up':    # keycode[273, 'up] pressed
            # Respond to keyboard up arrow pressed
            self.display_keystrokes(keyboard, keycode, text, modifiers)
            self.col1_row_controller.select_previous()
            self.col2_row_controller.select_previous()

        # Keycode is composed of an integer + a string
        # If we hit escape, release the keyboard
        if keycode[1] == 'escape':
            keyboard.release()

        # Return True to accept the key. Otherwise, it will be used by
        # the system.
        return True

    def display_keystrokes(self, keyboard, keycode, text, modifiers):
        print("\nThe key", keycode, "have been pressed")
        print(" - text is %r" % text)
        print(" - modifiers are %r" % modifiers)

    def on_keyboard_select(self):
        ''' Respond to keyboard event to call Popup '''

        # setup row data for Popup
        self.row_data = self.col1_data[self.col1_row_controller.selected_row]

        # call Popup
        self.popup_callback()

    def on_mouse_select(self, instance):
        ''' Respond to mouse event to call Popup '''

        if (self.col1_row_controller.selected_row != instance.index
                or self.col2_row_controller.selected_row != instance.index):
            # Mouse clicked on row is not equal to current selected row
            self.col1_row_controller.selected_row = instance.index
            self.col2_row_controller.selected_row = instance.index

            # Hightlight mouse clicked/selected row
            self.col1_row_controller.select_current()
            self.col2_row_controller.select_current()

        # setup row data for Popup
        # we can use either col1_data or col2_data because they are duplicate and each stores the same info
        self.row_data = self.col1_data[instance.index]

        # call Popup
        self.popup_callback()

    def popup_callback(self):

        # enable keyboard request
        self._request_keyboard()

    def set_default_first_row(self, dt):
        ''' Set default first row as selected '''
        self.col1_row_controller.select_next()
        self.col2_row_controller.select_next()

    def update(self):
        self.col1_data = [{'text': str(x[0]), 'Id': str(x[0]), 'Name': x[1], 'key': 'Id', 'selectable': True}
                          for x in self.data_items]

        self.col2_data = [{'text': x[1], 'Id': str(x[0]), 'Name': x[1], 'key': 'Name', 'selectable': True}
                          for x in self.data_items]

    def get_states(self):
        rows = [(1, 'abc'), (1, 'abc'),(1, 'abc'),(1, 'abc'),(1, 'abc'),(1, 'abc'),(1, 'abc'),(1, 'abc'),(1, 'abc'),(1, 'abc'),(1, 'abc'),(1, 'abc'),(1, 'abc'),(1, 'abc')]

        i = 0
        for row in rows:
            self.data_items.append([row[0], row[1], i])
            i += 1
        print(self.data_items)
        self.update()


class MainMenu(BoxLayout):
    states_cities_or_areas = ObjectProperty(None)
    rv = ObjectProperty(None)

    def display_states(self):
        self.remove_widgets()
        self.rv = RV()
        self.states_cities_or_areas.add_widget(self.rv)

    def remove_widgets(self):
        self.states_cities_or_areas.clear_widgets()


class TestApp(App):
    title = "test"

    def build(self):
        return MainMenu()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

## test.kv

```
#:kivy 1.10.0

<SelectableButton>:
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: (0, 0.517, 0.705, 1) if self.selected else (0, 0.517, 0.705, 1)
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
    background_color: [1, 0, 0, 1]  if self.selected else [1, 1, 1, 1]  # dark red else dark grey
    on_press: app.root.rv.on_mouse_select(self)


<RV>:
    col1_row_controller: col1_row_controller
    col2_row_controller: col2_row_controller

    orientation: "vertical"

    GridLayout:
        size_hint: 1, None
        size_hint_y: None
        height: 25
        cols: 3

        Label:
            size_hint_x: .1
            text: "Id"
        Label:
            size_hint_x: .5
            text: "Name"


    ScrollView:
        id: kr_scroll
        do_scroll_x: False
        height: 2
        BoxLayout:
            RecycleView:
                size_hint_x: .1
                data: root.col1_data
                viewclass: 'SelectableButton'
                SelectableRecycleGridLayout:
                    id: col1_row_controller
                    key_selection: 'selectable'
                    cols: 1
                    default_size: None, dp(26)
                    default_size_hint: 1, None
                    size_hint_y: None
                    height: self.minimum_height
                    orientation: 'vertical'
                    multiselect: True
                    touch_multiselect: True

            RecycleView:
                size_hint_x: .5
                data: root.col2_data
                viewclass: 'SelectableButton'
                SelectableRecycleGridLayout:
                    id: col2_row_controller
                    key_selection: 'selectable'
                    cols: 1
                    default_size: None, dp(26)
                    default_size_hint: 1, None
                    size_hint_y: None
                    height: self.minimum_height
                    orientation: 'vertical'
                    multiselect: True
                    touch_multiselect: True


<MenuButton@Button>:
    text_size: self.size
    valign: "middle"
    padding_x: 5
    size : (80,30)
    size_hint : (None, None)
    background_color: 90 , 90, 90, 90
    background_normal: ''
    color: 0, 0.517, 0.705, 1
    border: (0, 10, 0, 0)


<MainMenu>:
    states_cities_or_areas: states_cities_or_areas

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        #spacing : 10

        BoxLayout:
            canvas.before:
                Rectangle:
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size

            size_hint_y: 1

            MenuButton:
                id: btn
                text: 'Test'
                size : (60,30)
                on_release: root.display_states()


        BoxLayout:
            canvas.before:
                Rectangle:
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size

                Color:
                    rgb: (1,1,1)

            Label:
                size_hint_x: 45

        BoxLayout:
            id: states_cities_or_areas
            size_hint_y: 10

        Label:
            size_hint_y: 1
```

Comment: You need to use rows instead of columns in the view.

Comment: Are you wanting the two columns to scroll together?

Comment: @ jonyfries thanks. Yes i want only 1 scroll for two columns

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Question

> How to set text right align in only customerId column and other column
>   should be left align?

## Solution

### Snippet

```
def apply_selection(self, rv, index, is_selected):
    ''' Respond to the selection of items in the view. '''
    self.selected = is_selected
    self.text_size = self.size
    if index == rv.data[index]['range'][0]:
        self.halign = 'right'
    else:
        self.halign = 'left'
```

### Output

[image: Img8]

## Label - Text grow vertically and wraps at a certain width

A Label that can grow vertically but wraps the text at a certain width:

```
Label:
    size_hint_y: None
    text_size: self.width, None
    height: self.texture_size[1]
```

To scroll a GridLayout on it’s X-axis/horizontally and Y-axis/vertically, set size_hint property to (None, None).

[ScrollView - ScrollEffect, scroll_type, bar_width, etc.](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.scrollview.html)

> By default, the ScrollView allows scrolling along both the X and Y axes. You can explicitly disable scrolling on an axis by setting the do_scroll_x or do_scroll_y properties to False.
>
> To scroll a GridLayout on it’s Y-axis/vertically, set the child’s
>   width to that of the ScrollView (size_hint_x=1), and set the
>   size_hint_y property to None:
>
> When scrolling would exceed the bounds of the ScrollView, it uses a ScrollEffect to handle the overscroll.
>
> scroll_type
>
> Sets the type of scrolling to use for the content of the scrollview.
>   Available options are: [‘content’], [‘bars’], [‘bars’, ‘content’]
>
> [‘bars’]  Content is scrolled by dragging or swiping the scoll bars.

[Grid Layout](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.gridlayout.html)

> cols_minimum
>
> Dict of minimum width for each column. The dictionary keys are the
>   column numbers, e.g. 0, 1, 2…
>
> cols_minimum is a DictProperty and defaults to {}.

## Snippets

```
<RV>:
    row_controller: row_controller

    bar_width: 10
    bar_color: 1, 0, 0, 1   # red
    bar_inactive_color: 0, 0, 1, 1   # blue
    effect_cls: "ScrollEffect"
    scroll_type: ['bars']

    data: root.rv_data
    viewclass: 'SelectableButton'

    SelectableRecycleGridLayout:
        id: row_controller
        key_selection: 'selectable'
        cols: root.total_col_headings
        cols_minimum: root.cols_minimum
        default_size: None, dp(26)
        default_size_hint: 1, None
        size_hint: None, None
        height: self.minimum_height
        width: self.minimum_width
        orientation: 'vertical'
        multiselect: True
        touch_multiselect: True
```

The following example demonstrates:

1. Scrolling of the table header on the X-axis.
2. Support scrolling on the X-axis and Y-axis.
3. Support scrolling on the Y-axis in the Popup window.
4. Works for any columns in database table.
5. Varying column width using GridLayout *cols_minimum*.
6. Combined two RecycleView into one as there is no need to have a recycleview just for the ID.
7. Selectable buttons.

## SQLite Sample Database

[chinook SQLite sample database](http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-sample-database/)

## Example

### main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import BooleanProperty, ListProperty, ObjectProperty, NumericProperty, DictProperty

from kivy.uix.recycleview.views import RecycleDataViewBehavior
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.recyclegridlayout import RecycleGridLayout
from kivy.uix.behaviors import FocusBehavior
from kivy.uix.recycleview.layout import LayoutSelectionBehavior
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.recycleview import RecycleView
import sqlite3 as lite
import re

Window.size = (600, 325)


class PopupLabelCell(Label):
    pass


class EditStatePopup(Popup):

    def __init__(self, obj, **kwargs):
        super(EditStatePopup, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.populate_content(obj)

    def populate_content(self, obj):
        for x in range(len(obj.table_header.col_headings)):
            self.container.add_widget(PopupLabelCell(text=obj.table_header.col_headings[x]))
            textinput = TextInput(text=str(obj.row_data[x]))
            if x == 0:
                textinput.readonly = True
            self.container.add_widget(textinput)


class SelectableRecycleGridLayout(FocusBehavior, LayoutSelectionBehavior,
                                  RecycleGridLayout):
    ''' Adds selection and focus behaviour to the view. '''

    selected_row = NumericProperty(0)
    obj = ObjectProperty(None)

    def get_nodes(self):
        nodes = self.get_selectable_nodes()
        if self.nodes_order_reversed:
            nodes = nodes[::-1]
        if not nodes:
            return None, None

        selected = self.selected_nodes
        if not selected:    # nothing selected, select the first
            self.selected_row = 0
            self.select_row(nodes)
            return None, None

        if len(nodes) == 1:     # the only selectable node is selected already
            return None, None

        last = nodes.index(selected[-1])
        self.clear_selection()
        return last, nodes

    def select_next(self, obj):
        ''' Select next row '''
        self.obj = obj
        last, nodes = self.get_nodes()
        if not nodes:
            return

        if last == len(nodes) - 1:
            self.selected_row = nodes[0]
        else:
            self.selected_row = nodes[last + 1]

        self.selected_row += self.obj.total_col_headings
        self.select_row(nodes)

    def select_previous(self, obj):
        ''' Select previous row '''
        self.obj = obj
        last, nodes = self.get_nodes()
        if not nodes:
            return

        if not last:
            self.selected_row = nodes[-1]
        else:
            self.selected_row = nodes[last - 1]

        self.selected_row -= self.obj.total_col_headings
        self.select_row(nodes)

    def select_current(self, obj):
        ''' Select current row '''
        self.obj = obj
        last, nodes = self.get_nodes()
        if not nodes:
            return

        self.select_row(nodes)

    def select_row(self, nodes):
        col = self.obj.rv_data[self.selected_row]['range']
        for x in range(col[0], col[1] + 1):
            self.select_node(nodes[x])


class SelectableButton(RecycleDataViewBehavior, Button):
    ''' Add selection support to the Button '''
    index = None
    selected = BooleanProperty(False)
    selectable = BooleanProperty(True)

    def refresh_view_attrs(self, rv, index, data):
        ''' Catch and handle the view changes '''

        self.index = index
        return super(SelectableButton, self).refresh_view_attrs(rv, index, data)

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        ''' Add selection on touch down '''
        if super(SelectableButton, self).on_touch_down(touch):
            return True
        if self.collide_point(*touch.pos) and self.selectable:
            print("on_touch_down: self=", self)
            return self.parent.select_with_touch(self.index, touch)

    def apply_selection(self, rv, index, is_selected):
        ''' Respond to the selection of items in the view. '''
        self.selected = is_selected
        self.text_size = self.size
        if index == rv.data[index]['range'][0]:
            self.halign = 'right'
        else:
            self.halign = 'left'


class HeaderCell(Label):
    pass


class TableHeader(ScrollView):
    """Fixed table header that scrolls x with the data table"""
    header = ObjectProperty(None)
    col_headings = ListProperty([])
    cols_minimum = DictProperty({})

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(TableHeader, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.db = lite.connect('chinook.db')
        self.db_cursor = self.db.cursor()
        self.get_table_column_headings()

    def get_table_column_headings(self):
        self.db_cursor.execute("PRAGMA table_info(customers)")
        col_headings = self.db_cursor.fetchall()

        for col_heading in col_headings:
            data_type = col_heading[2]
            if data_type == "INTEGER":
                self.cols_minimum[col_heading[0]] = 100
            else:
                self.cols_minimum[col_heading[0]] = int(re.findall(r'\d+', data_type).pop(0)) * 5
            self.col_headings.append(col_heading[1])
            self.header.add_widget(HeaderCell(text=col_heading[1], width=self.cols_minimum[col_heading[0]]))


class RV(RecycleView):
    row_data = ()
    rv_data = ListProperty([])
    row_controller = ObjectProperty(None)
    total_col_headings = NumericProperty(0)
    cols_minimum = DictProperty({})
    table_header = ObjectProperty(None)

    def __init__(self, table_header, **kwargs):
        super(RV, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.table_header = table_header
        self.total_col_headings = len(table_header.col_headings)
        self.cols_minimum = table_header.cols_minimum
        self.database_connection()
        self.get_states()
        Clock.schedule_once(self.set_default_first_row, .0005)
        self._request_keyboard()

    def database_connection(self):
        self.db = lite.connect('chinook.db')
        self.db_cursor = self.db.cursor()

    def _request_keyboard(self):
        self._keyboard = Window.request_keyboard(
            self._keyboard_closed, self, 'text'
        )
        if self._keyboard.widget:
            # If it exists, this widget is a VKeyboard object which you can use
            # to change the keyboard layout.
            pass
        self._keyboard.bind(on_key_down=self._on_keyboard_down)

    def _keyboard_closed(self):
        self._keyboard.unbind(on_key_down=self._on_keyboard_down)
        self._keyboard = None

    def _on_keyboard_down(self, keyboard, keycode, text, modifiers):
        if keycode[1] == 'down':    # keycode[274, 'down'] pressed
            # Respond to keyboard down arrow pressed
            self.display_keystrokes(keyboard, keycode, text, modifiers)
            self.row_controller.select_next(self)

        elif keycode[1] == 'up':    # keycode[273, 'up] pressed
            # Respond to keyboard up arrow pressed
            self.display_keystrokes(keyboard, keycode, text, modifiers)
            self.row_controller.select_previous(self)

        elif len(modifiers) > 0 and modifiers[0] == 'ctrl' and text == 'e':     # ctrl + e pressed
            # Respond to keyboard ctrl + e pressed, and call Popup
            self.display_keystrokes(keyboard, keycode, text, modifiers)
            self.on_keyboard_select()

        # Keycode is composed of an integer + a string
        # If we hit escape, release the keyboard
        if keycode[1] == 'escape':
            keyboard.release()

        # Return True to accept the key. Otherwise, it will be used by
        # the system.
        return True

    def display_keystrokes(self, keyboard, keycode, text, modifiers):
        print("\nThe key", keycode, "have been pressed")
        print(" - text is %r" % text)
        print(" - modifiers are %r" % modifiers)

    def on_keyboard_select(self):
        ''' Respond to keyboard event to call Popup '''

        # setup row data for Popup
        self.setup_row_data(self.rv_data[self.row_controller.selected_row]['Index'])

        # call Popup
        self.popup_callback()

    def on_mouse_select(self, instance):
        ''' Respond to mouse event to call Popup '''

        if self.row_controller.selected_row != instance.index:
            # Mouse clicked on row is not equal to current selected row
            self.row_controller.selected_row = instance.index

            # Hightlight mouse clicked/selected row
            self.row_controller.select_current(self)

        # setup row data for Popup
        self.setup_row_data(self.rv_data[instance.index]['Index'])

        # call Popup
        self.popup_callback()

        # enable keyboard request
        self._request_keyboard()

    def setup_row_data(self, value):
        self.db_cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM customers WHERE CustomerId=?", value)
        self.row_data = self.db_cursor.fetchone()

    def popup_callback(self):
        ''' Instantiate and Open Popup '''
        popup = EditStatePopup(self)
        popup.open()

    def set_default_first_row(self, dt):
        ''' Set default first row as selected '''
        self.row_controller.select_next(self)

    def get_states(self):
        self.db_cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM customers ORDER BY CustomerId ASC")
        rows = self.db_cursor.fetchall()

        data = []
        low = 0
        high = self.total_col_headings - 1
        for row in rows:
            for i in range(len(row)):
                data.append([row[i], row[0], [low, high]])
            low += self.total_col_headings
            high += self.total_col_headings

        self.rv_data = [{'text': str(x[0]), 'Index': str(x[1]), 'range': x[2], 'selectable': True} for x in data]


class Table(BoxLayout):
    rv = ObjectProperty(None)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Table, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.orientation = "vertical"
        self.header = TableHeader()
        self.rv = RV(self.header)

        self.rv.fbind('scroll_x', self.scroll_with_header)

        self.add_widget(self.header)
        self.add_widget(self.rv)

    def scroll_with_header(self, obj, value):
        self.header.scroll_x = value


class MainMenu(BoxLayout):
    states_cities_or_areas = ObjectProperty(None)
    table = ObjectProperty(None)

    def display_states(self):
        self.remove_widgets()
        self.table = Table()
        self.states_cities_or_areas.add_widget(self.table)

    def remove_widgets(self):
        self.states_cities_or_areas.clear_widgets()


class TestApp(App):
    title = "test"

    def build(self):
        return MainMenu()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

### test.kv

```
#:kivy 1.10.0

<PopupLabelCell>
    size_hint: (None, None)
    height: 30
    text_size: self.size
    halign: "left"
    valign: "middle"

<EditStatePopup>:
    container: container
    size_hint: None, None
    size: 400, 275
    title_size: 20
    # title_font: "Verdana"
    auto_dismiss: False

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        ScrollView:
            bar_width: 10
            bar_color: 1, 0, 0, 1   # red
            bar_inactive_color: 0, 0, 1, 1   # blue
            effect_cls: "ScrollEffect"
            scroll_type: ['bars']
            size_hint: (1, None)

            GridLayout:
                id: container
                cols: 2
                row_default_height: 30
                cols_minimum: {0: 100, 1: 300}
                # spacing: 10, 10
                # padding: 20, 20
                size_hint: (None, None)
                height: self.minimum_height

        BoxLayout:
            Button:
                size_hint: 1, 0.2
                text: "Save Changes"
                on_release:
                    root.dismiss()
            Button:
                size_hint: 1, 0.2
                text: "Cancel Changes"
                on_release: root.dismiss()

<SelectableButton>:
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: (0, 0.517, 0.705, 1) if self.selected else (0, 0.517, 0.705, 1)
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
    background_color: [1, 0, 0, 1]  if self.selected else [1, 1, 1, 1]  # dark red else dark grey
    on_press: app.root.table.rv.on_mouse_select(self)

<HeaderCell>
    size_hint: (None, None)
    height: 25
    text_size: self.size
    halign: "left"
    valign: "middle"
    background_disabled_normal: ''
    disabled_color: (1, 1, 1, 1)

    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: 1, 0.502, 0, 1
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size

<TableHeader>:
    header: header
    bar_width: 0
    do_scroll: False
    size_hint: (1, None)
    height: 25
    effect_cls: "ScrollEffect"

    GridLayout:
        id: header
        rows: 1
        cols_minimum: root.cols_minimum
        size_hint: (None, None)
        width: self.minimum_width
        height: self.minimum_height

<RV>:
    row_controller: row_controller

    bar_width: 10
    bar_color: 1, 0, 0, 1   # red
    bar_inactive_color: 0, 0, 1, 1   # blue
    effect_cls: "ScrollEffect"
    scroll_type: ['bars']

    data: root.rv_data
    viewclass: 'SelectableButton'

    SelectableRecycleGridLayout:
        id: row_controller
        key_selection: 'selectable'
        cols: root.total_col_headings
        cols_minimum: root.cols_minimum
        default_size: None, dp(26)
        default_size_hint: 1, None
        size_hint: None, None
        height: self.minimum_height
        width: self.minimum_width
        orientation: 'vertical'
        multiselect: True
        touch_multiselect: True


<MenuButton@Button>:
    text_size: self.size
    valign: "middle"
    padding_x: 5
    size : (80,30)
    size_hint : (None, None)
    background_color: 90 , 90, 90, 90
    background_normal: ''
    color: 0, 0.517, 0.705, 1
    border: (0, 10, 0, 0)


<MainMenu>:
    states_cities_or_areas: states_cities_or_areas

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'

        BoxLayout:
            canvas.before:
                Rectangle:
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size

            size_hint_y: 1

            MenuButton:
                id: btn
                text: 'Test'
                size : (60,30)
                on_release: root.display_states()


        BoxLayout:
            canvas.before:
                Rectangle:
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size

                Color:
                    rgb: (1,1,1)

            Label:
                size_hint_x: 45

        BoxLayout:
            id: states_cities_or_areas
            size_hint_y: 10

        Label:
            size_hint_y: 1
```

## Output

[image: Img01]
[image: Img02]
[image: Img03]
[image]

Comment: How to Wrap Text automatically in listing and set row height accordingly

Comment: @Martin: I have updated my post for wrapping text and set height accordingly.

Comment: Please can  you tell me  how to set text `right align` in only  `customerId` column and other column should be `left align`.Thank u so much

Comment: Please refer to updated post for solution to text alignment.

Answer (score 4):

The trick is to change the `viewclass` to fit your needs. You had used `Button` but it looked to me like that was just to try to sync up your two `RecycleViews` so I used Labels instead. However, since the TwoLabelListItem that I created is just a BoxLayout you can easily manipulate it to exactly fit your needs.

Once you create the appropriate layout for the `viewclass` you then just need to make sure that your the data passed to it is correctly applied. Here I apply the data to the two different labels. I also grab the data as your notes indicated you wanted to be able to have something popup for the different line items.

```
def refresh_view_attrs(self, rv, index, data):
    ''' Catch and handle the view changes '''
    self.index = index
    self.ids.label1.text = data['text1']
    self.ids.label2.text = data['text2']
    self.data = data
```

So keeping the data will let you reference it when an element is selected.

```
    def apply_selection(self, rv, index, is_selected):
        ''' Respond to the selection of items in the view. '''
        self.selected = is_selected
        if self.selected:
            print(self.data)
```

Adding a scroll bar to the RecycleView is then simply a matter of telling it in kv that you want to use it. If you want to have the user be able to either move the content or the bars just add content to the list. `['bars', 'content']`

```
RecycleView:        
    scroll_type: ['bars']
    bar_width: 25
    ...
```

testApp.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import BooleanProperty, ListProperty, ObjectProperty, NumericProperty, DictProperty

from kivy.uix.recycleview.views import RecycleDataViewBehavior
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.recyclegridlayout import RecycleGridLayout
from kivy.uix.behaviors import FocusBehavior
from kivy.uix.recycleview.layout import LayoutSelectionBehavior
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.clock import Clock

Window.size = (600, 325)


class SelectableRecycleGridLayout(FocusBehavior, LayoutSelectionBehavior,
                                  RecycleGridLayout):
    ''' Adds selection and focus behaviour to the view. '''

    selected_row = NumericProperty(0)

    def get_nodes(self):
        nodes = self.get_selectable_nodes()
        if self.nodes_order_reversed:
            nodes = nodes[::-1]
        if not nodes:
            return None, None

        selected = self.selected_nodes
        if not selected:    # nothing selected, select the first
            self.select_node(nodes[0])
            self.selected_row = 0
            return None, None

        if len(nodes) == 1:     # the only selectable node is selected already
            return None, None

        last = nodes.index(selected[-1])
        self.clear_selection()
        return last, nodes

    def select_next(self):
        ''' Select next row '''
        last, nodes = self.get_nodes()
        if not nodes:
            return

        if last == len(nodes) - 1:
            self.select_node(nodes[0])
            self.selected_row = nodes[0]
        else:
            self.select_node(nodes[last + 1])
            self.selected_row = nodes[last + 1]

    def select_previous(self):
        ''' Select previous row '''
        last, nodes = self.get_nodes()
        if not nodes:
            return

        if not last:
            self.select_node(nodes[-1])
            self.selected_row = nodes[-1]
        else:
            self.select_node(nodes[last - 1])
            self.selected_row = nodes[last - 1]

    def select_current(self):
        ''' Select current row '''
        last, nodes = self.get_nodes()
        if not nodes:
            return

        self.select_node(nodes[self.selected_row])


class TwoLabelListItem(RecycleDataViewBehavior, BoxLayout):
    ''' Add selection support to the Label '''
    index = None
    selected = BooleanProperty(False)
    selectable = BooleanProperty(True)

    def refresh_view_attrs(self, rv, index, data):
        ''' Catch and handle the view changes '''
        self.index = index
        self.ids.label1.text = data['text1']
        self.ids.label2.text = data['text2']
        self.data = data

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        ''' Add selection on touch down '''
        if super(TwoLabelListItem, self).on_touch_down(touch):
            return True
        if self.collide_point(*touch.pos) and self.selectable:
            return self.parent.select_with_touch(self.index, touch)

    def apply_selection(self, rv, index, is_selected):
        ''' Respond to the selection of items in the view. '''
        self.selected = is_selected
        if self.selected:
            print(self.data)


class RV(BoxLayout):
    data_items = ListProperty([])
    row_data = DictProperty({})
    data = ListProperty([])
    col_row_controller = ObjectProperty(None)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(RV, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.get_states()
        Clock.schedule_once(self.set_default_first_row, .0005)
        self._request_keyboard()

    def _request_keyboard(self):
        self._keyboard = Window.request_keyboard(
            self._keyboard_closed, self, 'text'
        )
        if self._keyboard.widget:
            # If it exists, this widget is a VKeyboard object which you can use
            # to change the keyboard layout.
            pass
        self._keyboard.bind(on_key_down=self._on_keyboard_down)

    def _keyboard_closed(self):
        self._keyboard.unbind(on_key_down=self._on_keyboard_down)
        self._keyboard = None

    def _on_keyboard_down(self, keyboard, keycode, text, modifiers):
        if keycode[1] == 'down':    # keycode[274, 'down'] pressed
            # Respond to keyboard down arrow pressed
            self.display_keystrokes(keyboard, keycode, text, modifiers)
            self.col_row_controller.select_next()

        elif keycode[1] == 'up':    # keycode[273, 'up] pressed
            # Respond to keyboard up arrow pressed
            self.display_keystrokes(keyboard, keycode, text, modifiers)
            self.col_row_controller.select_previous()

        # Keycode is composed of an integer + a string
        # If we hit escape, release the keyboard
        if keycode[1] == 'escape':
            keyboard.release()

        # Return True to accept the key. Otherwise, it will be used by
        # the system.
        return True

    def display_keystrokes(self, keyboard, keycode, text, modifiers):
        print("\nThe key", keycode, "have been pressed")
        print(" - text is %r" % text)
        print(" - modifiers are %r" % modifiers)

    def on_keyboard_select(self):
        ''' Respond to keyboard event to call Popup '''

        # setup row data for Popup
        self.row_data = self.data[self.col_row_controller.selected_row]

        # call Popup
        self.popup_callback()

    def on_mouse_select(self, instance):
        ''' Respond to mouse event to call Popup '''

        if (self.col_row_controller.selected_row != instance.index):
            # Mouse clicked on row is not equal to current selected row
            self.col_row_controller.selected_row = instance.index

            # Hightlight mouse clicked/selected row
            self.col_row_controller.select_current()

        # setup row data for Popup
        self.row_data = self.data[instance.index]

        # call Popup
        self.popup_callback()

    def popup_callback(self):

        # enable keyboard request
        self._request_keyboard()

    def set_default_first_row(self, dt):
        ''' Set default first row as selected '''
        self.col_row_controller.select_next()

    def update(self):
        self.data = [{'text1': str(x[0]), 'text2': x[1], 'Id': str(x[0]), 'Name': x[1], 'key': 'Id', 'selectable': True}
                          for x in self.data_items]

    def get_states(self):
        rows = [(x, 'abc') for x in range(25)]

        i = 0
        for row in rows:
            self.data_items.append([row[0], row[1], i])
            i += 1
        print(self.data_items)
        self.update()


class MainMenu(BoxLayout):
    states_cities_or_areas = ObjectProperty(None)
    rv = ObjectProperty(None)

    def display_states(self):
        self.remove_widgets()
        self.rv = RV()
        self.states_cities_or_areas.add_widget(self.rv)

    def remove_widgets(self):
        self.states_cities_or_areas.clear_widgets()


class TestApp(App):
    title = "test"

    def build(self):
        return MainMenu()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

test.kv

```
#:kivy 1.10.0

<TwoLabelListItem>:
    # Draw a background to indicate selection
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: (.0, 0.9, .1, .3) if self.selected else (0, 0, 0, 1)
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
    Label:
        id: label1
    Label:
        id: label2


<RV>:
    col_row_controller: col_row_controller
    RecycleView:
        scroll_type: ['bars']
        bar_width: 25
        size_hint_x: .1
        data: root.data
        viewclass: 'TwoLabelListItem'
        SelectableRecycleGridLayout:
            padding: 0,0,25,0
            id: col_row_controller
            key_selection: 'selectable'
            cols: 1
            default_size: None, dp(26)
            default_size_hint: 1, None
            size_hint_y: None
            height: self.minimum_height
            orientation: 'vertical'
            multiselect: False
            touch_multiselect: True


<MenuButton@Button>:
    text_size: self.size
    valign: "middle"
    padding_x: 5
    size : (80,30)
    size_hint : (None, None)
    background_color: 90 , 90, 90, 90
    background_normal: ''
    color: 0, 0.517, 0.705, 1
    border: (0, 10, 0, 0)


<MainMenu>:
    states_cities_or_areas: states_cities_or_areas

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        #spacing : 10

        BoxLayout:
            canvas.before:
                Rectangle:
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size

            size_hint_y: 1

            MenuButton:
                id: btn
                text: 'Test'
                size : (60,30)
                on_release: root.display_states()


        BoxLayout:
            canvas.before:
                Rectangle:
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size

                Color:
                    rgb: (1,1,1)

            Label:
                size_hint_x: 45

        BoxLayout:
            id: states_cities_or_areas
            size_hint_y: 10

        Label:
            size_hint_y: 1
```