# Kivy Multiple Column RecyclerView

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

i was just playing with `Python` and `kivy` , I've loaded my String data into a `RecyclerView` as per the kivy official documentation. but I've faced trouble on loading an object to multiple columns inside the list like a form data. for example i wanted to have name,family name and age to three columns with title headers row by row , I've also tried `RecyclerGridLayout` with 3 columns , but it can load just name into grids regardless of row by row requirement

```
<RV>:
    viewclass: 'Label'
    RecycleBoxLayout:
        default_size: None, dp(56)
        default_size_hint: 1, None
        size_hint_y: None
        height: self.minimum_height
        orientation: 'vertical'
```

Will appreciate any hint or sample code to learn how RecyclerView works on `kivy`

Comment: Please check this post, [RecycleView with multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50219281/python-how-to-add-vertical-scroll-in-recycleview/50299444#50299444)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was also looking for this and I could not find a specific example, so I have provided my solution. As el3ien has said, you will need to create a custom class which will represent each row of your selectable label.

```
<SelectableLabel>:
# Draw a background to indicate selection
canvas.before:
    Color:
        rgba: (.0, 0.9, .1, .3) if self.selected else (0, 0, 0, 1)
    Rectangle:
        pos: self.pos
        size: self.size
label1_text: 'label 1 text'  # I have included two methods of accessing the labels
label2_text: 'label 2 text'  # This is method 1
label3_text: 'label 3 text'
pos: self.pos
size: self.size
Label:
    id: id_label1  # method 2 uses the label id
    text: root.label1_text
Label:
    id: id_label2
    text: root.label2_text
Label:
    id: id_label3
    text: root.label3_text
```

In applying your data into the RV, you will need to restructure the dictionary to reflect the label layout

```
class RV(RecycleView):
def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    super(RV, self).__init__(**kwargs)
    paired_iter = zip(items_1, items_2)  # items_1 and items_2 are defined elsewhere
    self.data = []
    for i1, i2 in paired_iter:
        d = {'label2': {'text': i1}, 'label3': {'text': i2}}
        self.data.append(d)
```

Finally in the refresh_view_attrs, you will specify .label_text which is bound to each label, or you can use label id's.

```
def refresh_view_attrs(self, rv, index, data):
    ''' Catch and handle the view changes '''
    self.index = index
    self.label1_text = str(index)
    self.label2_text = data['label2']['text']
    self.ids['id_label3'].text = data['label3']['text']  # As an alternate method of assignment
    return super(SelectableLabel, self).refresh_view_attrs(
        rv, index, data)
```

The entire code is below:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.recycleview import RecycleView
from kivy.uix.recycleview.views import RecycleDataViewBehavior
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.properties import BooleanProperty
from kivy.uix.recycleboxlayout import RecycleBoxLayout
from kivy.uix.behaviors import FocusBehavior
from kivy.uix.recycleview.layout import LayoutSelectionBehavior

Builder.load_string('''
<SelectableLabel>:
    # Draw a background to indicate selection
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: (.0, 0.9, .1, .3) if self.selected else (0, 0, 0, 1)
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
    label1_text: 'label 1 text'
    label2_text: 'label 2 text'
    label3_text: 'label 3 text'
    pos: self.pos
    size: self.size
    Label:
        id: id_label1
        text: root.label1_text
    Label:
        id: id_label2
        text: root.label2_text
    Label:
        id: id_label3
        text: root.label3_text

<RV>:
    viewclass: 'SelectableLabel'
    SelectableRecycleBoxLayout:
        default_size: None, dp(56)
        default_size_hint: 1, None
        size_hint_y: None
        height: self.minimum_height
        orientation: 'vertical'
        multiselect: True
        touch_multiselect: True
''')


items_1 = {'apple', 'banana', 'pear', 'pineapple'}
items_2 = {'dog', 'cat', 'rat', 'bat'}


class SelectableRecycleBoxLayout(FocusBehavior, LayoutSelectionBehavior,
                                 RecycleBoxLayout):
    ''' Adds selection and focus behaviour to the view. '''


class SelectableLabel(RecycleDataViewBehavior, GridLayout):
    ''' Add selection support to the Label '''
    index = None
    selected = BooleanProperty(False)
    selectable = BooleanProperty(True)
    cols = 3

    def refresh_view_attrs(self, rv, index, data):
        ''' Catch and handle the view changes '''
        self.index = index
        self.label1_text = str(index)
        self.label2_text = data['label2']['text']
        self.ids['id_label3'].text = data['label3']['text']  # As an alternate method of assignment
        return super(SelectableLabel, self).refresh_view_attrs(
            rv, index, data)

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        ''' Add selection on touch down '''
        if super(SelectableLabel, self).on_touch_down(touch):
            return True
        if self.collide_point(*touch.pos) and self.selectable:
            return self.parent.select_with_touch(self.index, touch)

    def apply_selection(self, rv, index, is_selected):
        ''' Respond to the selection of items in the view. '''
        self.selected = is_selected
        if is_selected:
            print("selection changed to {0}".format(rv.data[index]))
        else:
            print("selection removed for {0}".format(rv.data[index]))


class RV(RecycleView):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(RV, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        paired_iter = zip(items_1, items_2)
        self.data = []
        for i1, i2 in paired_iter:
            d = {'label2': {'text': i1}, 'label3': {'text': i2}}
            self.data.append(d)
        # can also be performed in a complicated one liner for those who like it tricky
        # self.data = [{'label2': {'text': i1}, 'label3': {'text': i2}} for i1, i2 in zip(items_1, items_2)]


class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return RV()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

Comment: Note: "SelectableLabel" is a misnomer. It's not a label, it's a GridLayout. The name is a legacy of the example it was derived from.

Comment: Yes, you are right. It could be edited to SelectableGridItem or similar.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using `Label` as viewclass, create a custom class. That could be a horizontal box layout with two boxes.

```
<CustomClass@BoxLayout>:
    orientation: "horizontal"
    Label:
    Label:
```

Answer (score 3):

I used the above idea from @el3ien. My code is below.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.recycleview import RecycleView
Builder.load_string('''
<RV>:
    viewclass: 'myView'
    RecycleBoxLayout:
        default_size: None, dp(200)
        default_size_hint: 1, None
        size_hint_y: None
        height: self.minimum_height
        orientation: 'vertical'


<myView@BoxLayout>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'horizontal'


        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            on_release:

            Button:
                size_hint: (1,1)
                background_normal: 'C:/Users/Arsalan/Desktop/dummyImage2.jpg'
                background_down: 'C:/Users/Arsalan/Desktop/dummyImage1.png'
                text: 
                text_size: self.size
                halign: 
                valign: 'middle'

            Label:
                size_hint: (1,0.3)
                text: 'Product summary'
                text_size: self.size 
                halign:
                valign: 'middle'
                canvas.before:
                    Color:
                        rgba: (0.6, 0.7, 0.4, 1)
                    Rectangle:
                        size: self.size
                        pos: self.pos
            BoxLayout:
                size_hint :(1,0.01)

            Label:
                size_hint: (1,0.3)
                text: 'Rs 600'
                text_size: self.size 
                halign:
                valign: 'middle'




        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            size_hint: (0.001,1)




        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            on_release:

            Button:
                size_hint: (1,1)
                background_normal: 'C:/Users/Arsalan/Desktop/dummyImage2.jpg'
                background_down: 'C:/Users/Arsalan/Desktop/dummyImage1.png'
                text: 
                text_size: self.size
                halign: 
                valign: 'middle'

            Label:
                size_hint: (1,0.3)
                text: 'Product summary'
                text_size: self.size 
                halign:
                valign: 'middle'
                canvas.before:
                    Color:
                        rgba: (0.6, 0.7, 0.4, 1)
                    Rectangle:
                        size: self.size
                        pos: self.pos
            BoxLayout:
                size_hint :(1,0.01)

            Label:
                size_hint: (1,0.3)
                text: 'Rs 600'
                text_size: self.size 
                halign:
                valign: 'middle'




''')
class RV(RecycleView):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(RV, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.data = [{'text': str(x)} for x in range(100)]
class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return RV()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

Try it out and let me know if you still have any question.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add a headers row to the table; and, I am trying the following:

```
<RV>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'horizontal'
            size_hint: 1, None
            size_hint_y: None
            height: 25
            Label:
                text: "Item"
            Label:
                text: "User ID"
            Label:
                text: "User Name"

        BoxLayout:
            RecycleView:
                id: review
                viewclass: 'SelectableLabel'
                SelectableRecycleBoxLayout:
                    default_size: None, dp(56)
                    default_size_hint: 1, None
                    size_hint_y: None
                    height: self.minimum_height
                    orientation: 'vertical'
                    multiselect: True
                    touch_multiselect: True
```

But then the :SelectableRecycleBoxLayout moves deeper into the hierarchy and I no longer get the table, only the headers...how to fix this?  I still don't quite get how to get to kv stuff from the python. :-(