# Changing the color of cell and sizing the content

Tags: kivy, kivy-language

In the following answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/56140831/9440453 how can i change the color of cell based on the values in it and also how can i fit the content within the cell or resize the cell based on the content size.

**Details For color:** 
      If cell contains `kyle` the color should be `red` and if it contains `raul` it should be `blue` and so on

Which property we should edit to make this work.

Comment: Do want to change the color of the text or canvas of the cell?

Comment: canvas of the cell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Question 3 - text colour

> how can i change the text color?

### Solution 3 - Label color

Use `color` to change the text colour

#### Note

> The [Button](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.button.html) is a [Label](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.label.html) with associated actions that are
>   triggered when the button is pressed (or released after a
>   click/touch). To configure the button, the same properties (padding,
>   font_size, etc) and sizing system are used as for the Label class.

#### [Kivy Label » color](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.label.html#kivy.uix.label.Label.color)

> ```
> color
> ```
>
> Text color, in the format (r, g, b, a).
>
> color is a [ListProperty](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.properties.html#kivy.properties.ListProperty) and defaults to [1, 1, 1, 1].

#### Snippets

```
def apply_selection(self, rv, index, is_selected):
    ''' Respond to the selection of items in the view. '''

    self.selected = is_selected

    if rv.data[index]['text'].lower() == 'kyle':
        self.color = [0, 1, 0, 1]  # green colour text
        ...
    elif rv.data[index]['text'].lower() == 'raul':
        self.color = [0, 1, 1, 1]  # aqua colour text
        ...
    else:
        self.color = [1, 1, 1, 1]  # default white colour text
        ...
```

## Question 1 - resize cell based on content

> how can i fit the content within the cell or resize the cell based on the content size.

### Solution 1 - Label texture_size

To set the size to the text content, bind `size` to `texture_size` to grow with the text.

#### [Kivy Label » texture_size](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.label.html#kivy.uix.label.Label.texture_size)

> ```
> texture_size
> ```
>
> Texture size of the text. The size is determined by the font size and
>   text. If [text_size](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.label.html#kivy.uix.label.Label.text_size) is [None, None], the texture will be the size
>   required to fit the text, otherwise it’s clipped to fit
>   [text_size](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.label.html#kivy.uix.label.Label.text_size).
>
> When [text_size](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.label.html#kivy.uix.label.Label.text_size) is [None, None], one can bind to texture_size and
>   rescale it proportionally to fit the size of the label in order to
>   make the text fit maximally in the label.
>
> Warning
>
> The texture_size is set after the [texture](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.label.html#kivy.uix.label.Label.texture) property. If you listen
>   for changes to [texture](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.label.html#kivy.uix.label.Label.texture), texture_size will not be up-to-date in
>   your callback. Bind to texture_size instead.

#### Snippets

```
<Label>:
    size: self.texture_size

<TextInputPopup>:
    title: "Popup"
```

## Question 2 - color cell according to data

> how can i change the color of cell based on the values in it

### Solution 2

The solution requires changes to the Python script.

#### Py file

- Check for key e.g. *kyle* or *raul* in the method `apply_selection(self, rv, index, is_selected)` and set the rgba to red or blue respectively.
- Change the colour by using Button's attributes, `background_color` and `background_normal` together.

#### [Kivy Button » background_color](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.button.html#kivy.uix.button.Button.background_color)

> ```
> background_color
> ```
>
> Background color, in the format (r, g, b, a).
>
> This acts as a multiplier to the texture colour. The default texture
>   is grey, so just setting the background color will give a darker
>   result. To set a plain color, set the [background_normal](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.button.html#kivy.uix.button.Button.background_normal) to ''.
>
> The background_color is a [ListProperty](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.properties.html#kivy.properties.ListProperty) and defaults to [1, 1, 1,
>   1].

#### [Kivy Button » background_normal](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.button.html#kivy.uix.button.Button.background_normal)

> ```
> background_normal
> ```
>
> Background image of the button used for the default graphical
>   representation when the button is not pressed.
>
> background_normal is a [StringProperty](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.properties.html#kivy.properties.StringProperty) and defaults to
>   ‘atlas://data/images/defaulttheme/button’.

#### Snippets

```
def apply_selection(self, rv, index, is_selected):
    ''' Respond to the selection of items in the view. '''

    self.selected = is_selected

    if rv.data[index]['text'].lower() == 'kyle':
        self.background_color = [1, 0, 0, 1]    # red background colour
        self.background_normal = ''
    elif rv.data[index]['text'].lower() == 'raul':
        self.background_color = [0, 0, 1, 1]    # blue background colour
        self.background_normal = ''
    else:
        self.background_color = [1, 1, 1, 1]    # default colour
        self.background_normal = 'atlas://data/images/defaulttheme/button'    # default
```

## Output

[image: Result]

Comment: if i apply the color for `mark` some other cells are also getting affected as in below screenshot https://imgur.com/a/7HoMiBV

Comment: Please refer to updated post for resetting the colour.

Comment: color works brilliantly well, Kivy is super awesome, never knew we could do such things.. i think i am not clear with content sizing question. I want the cell width to be exactly in size with the content width

Comment: and also how can i change the text color? should i create a separate question for it?

Comment: Please refer to updated post for solutions to text colour and resize based on content.

Comment: For resizing, should i do anything other than giving `size: self.texture_size` in .kv file?

Comment: As for resizing to content - nothing, just `size: self.texture_size`.

Comment: for some reason , the resize not happening as expected

Comment: Try replacing `size_hint: 1, None` with `size_hint: None, None` for both `GridLayout`s. The result is not very pretty. Due to this, I prefer to use `cols_minimum`.